# JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL is not woking as expected

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. I want to remove null attributes from request object. This is because I need to pass the request object to 3rd party API without null attributes for the next step. I've searched on the internet and found that I can use **JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL**. But the object still has null values. Below are my example codes,

**Model,**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestTest {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer age;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Controller,**

```
@PostMapping("/test/person")
public String testPerson(@RequestBody RequestTest req){
    log.info(gson.toJson(req)); //I need to pass this to 3rd party API without null fields.
    return "success";
}
```

And here what I got from the logs,

```
{
  "firstname": "foo",
  "lastname": null,
  "age": 15
}
```

The object still contains null value. Please help.

**Edited**

This is the example code I need to pass the object to 3rd party API,

```
public String passToThirdParty(RequestTest req){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String url = "/xxx";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<RequestTest> entity = new HttpEntity<>( req, headers);

    log.info(gson.toJson(entity)); //Inside body, it still has "lastname": null.

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    return result.getBody();
}
```

Inside the body of entity's logs, it still has **"lastname":null**
Please help. Or do I need to remove it manually field by field ?

Comment: `JsonInclude` is a Jackson Annotation, you're passing the value to a GSON-Serializer

Comment: @codeflush.dev Then how can I remove it because I need to pass it to outside without null attrs. ps. I added more example code to connect to outside third party.

Comment: Use `ObjectMapper` instead of `Gson` or find the matching annotation/configuration for gson